# Android client - server never detect connection lost

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, client-server

My situation is the following:

Two devices, both running with Android OS,

One Devices is the server, this is running with a Service and running threads to create connections and all the normal protocol,

the other is any client with android devices, this also runs a service with the nescesary threads to connect.

Everything works properly, even if the client close the app, sends a notification to the server and this close the socket, and if the server stops properly also.

**The problem** is when the server shutdown suddenly (Power off) or lose the wifi.

Then the client never detects that the server has stop impling that the socket is broken, for never I mean never. I wait even few minutes and the connection is still alive. 
Also I add a system that sends every 20s a packet using ObjectOutputStream, but this is sent without any exception.

Why this is happening? How can I solve this problem?

I've read few post with problems with this but any solution has work for me.

This is the server thread connection:

```
@Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.run();
            try {
                mSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
                mSocket.setSoTimeout(20 * 1000);
                mOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());
                mInput = new ObjectInputStream(mSocket.getInputStream());
                while (mSocket.isConnected() && isAlive) {
                    try {
                        MotePacket packet = (MotePacket) mInput.readObject();
                        if (packet==null) continue;
                        MotePacket result = renderPacket(packet);
                        if (result==null) continue;
                        mOutput.writeObject(result);
                        mOutput.flush();
                        if (!isAccepted) break;
                    } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException ste) {
                        continue;
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                        continue;
                    } catch (StreamCorruptedException ex) {
                        continue;
                    }

                }
                closeSocket();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    closeSocket();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

And this is the client thread:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();
        try {
            mSocket = new Socket(mIp, mPort + 1);
            mSocket.setSoTimeout(10 * 1000);
            ;// Log.v("MPB", "Sck connected " + mSocket.isConnected());
            mOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());
            mInput = new ObjectInputStream(mSocket.getInputStream());
            ;// Log.v("MPB", "Socket");
            isAlive = true;
            mOutput.writeObject(new MotePacket(Type.DISCOVERY,new ConnectPacket(android_id, DeviceInfo.getDeviceName())));
            mOutput.flush();
            while (mSocket.isConnected() && isAlive) {
                try {
                    MotePacket packet = (MotePacket) mInput.readObject();
                    if (packet==null) continue; 
                    switch (packet.getHeader()) {
                    case DISCOVERY:
                        DiscoveryPacket data = (DiscoveryPacket) packet
                                .getPayload();
                        if (data.getAck() == EngelAck.ENGEL_REJECT) {
                            isAlive = false;
                            mCallback.onConnectionReject();
                            break;
                        }
                        mCallback.onConnectionStablished(data.getNative_service_port());
                        break;
                    case CONNECTION:
                        ;// Log.v("MPB", "Packet connection recevied");
                        mCallback.onPacketReceived((NetPacket) packet.getPayload());
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException ste) {
                    mSocket.sendUrgentData(1);
                    continue;
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    continue;
                } catch (StreamCorruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    continue;
                }

            }
            ;// Log.v("MPB", "Socket dead");
            mCallback.onConnectionLost();
            mSocket.shutdownOutput();
            mSocket.shutdownInput();
            mSocket.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ;// Log.v("MPB", "Socket Exception, closing it");
            mCallback.onConnectionLost();
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                mSocket.shutdownOutput();
                mSocket.shutdownInput();
                mSocket.close();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I know it looks quite with full of crap, but are just to check everything.
If anyone can help me I will appreciate

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

If anyone is interesed on how to solve this, I finally did the Heartbeat protocol that @Nikolai N Fetissov comments.

To do it I made a new thread with a timeout, that if the server have not replied after sending the packet this stop the conexion and notify the client

```
Handler hReply;
Runnable checkReply = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("MPB", "Check if closed");
            isAlive=false;
            mCallback.onConnectionLost();
            try {
                mSocket.shutdownOutput();
                mSocket.shutdownInput();
                mSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.i("MPB", "Already closed");
            }
    }

};

public void sendPacketToJavaServer(EngelMotePacket packet) throws Exception {
    if (mOutput!=null) {
        if (hReply!=null)
            hReply.removeCallbacks(checkReply);
        hReply = new Handler();
        Log.v("MPB", "send packet to server");
        mOutput.writeObject(packet);
        mOutput.flush();
        hReply.postDelayed(checkReply, DELAY_REPLY);
    }
    else 
        throw new SocketTimeoutException();
}
```

And then on the part that the client receiv answers remove the callbacks if an answer is received

```
if (hReply !=null) {
Log.i("MPB", "remove check if closed");
hReply.removeCallbacks(checkReply);
}
```

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conventional approach to this sort of issues is to implement an **application-level protocol heartbeat**. Say if there's no other application data to be sent over the connection send a heartbeat message after `N` seconds of inactivity. This means the other side can assume the connection is dead after receiving no messages for longer then`N` seconds.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it that this would work, but I wanted to avoid, anyway with this, every 20s I'm sending a byte and if in 10s is not receiving a reply I close the connexion.

Answer (score 0):

> Also I add a system that sends every 20s a packet using ObjectOutputStream, but this is sent without any exception.

TCP uses the retransmission timer to detect send failures, but it can take some time (even 10 min.). So it's possible that send does not return error because the data is sent from the host but not arrived. Try to wait 15 minutes to see if send is still successful.

Comment: Anyway if this is like you says, is totally unacceptable for my app. So finally I decided to implement a heartbeat protocol as @Nikolai N Fetissov says. I wanted to avoid this but seams the unique solution